# terminal errors when running gulp

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I am getting these errors when i run gulp command. what is causing this?

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:375:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:406:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:345:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:302:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:355:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:13:17)
  at execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^3.7.0/index.js:23:3)
  at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js:150:63)
  at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:192:16)
```

Comment: syntax error means that you typed smth wrong...we need more information. Pls edit it and show also the command

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a `:` instead of `;` in your `gulpfile.js` on line 29.